# How to Pass String Parameters in JavaScript and Check it with Current Time

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and started doing small application which works like this:

1. My App takes time as input and should match with current time
2. If it matches then a Notification should get displayed

Here is the code which takes input but it's not Displaying Notification, I didn't build my code properly as I'm new to JavaScript.
And help me how to display with PM and AM.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

Current Time<p id="CurrentTime"></p>
Enter The Time <input type="text"  id="textbox">
<button onclick="notifyMe()">Notify!</button>

<p id='input' >hello</p>
<p id="time"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout("ShowTime()", 1000);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date();
var tempcheck=null;
alert("Showing time");
function ShowTime() {
    var temptime="15:27";

    var d1 = new Date();
    var d2 = new Date();

    d1.setHours(+d2.getHours());
    d1.setMinutes(new Date().getMinutes());
    var ftime=d1.getHours()+":"+d1.getMinutes()+":"+d1.getSeconds();
    var tempcheck=d1.getHours()+":"+d1.getMinutes();
    document.getElementById("CurrentTime").innerHTML = ftime;

    window.setTimeout("ShowTime()", 1000);
} //Showtime ends
</script>


<script>
var take_input=null;
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date();
var ftimec=null;


function CheckTime(take_input){
    d1.setHours(+d2.getHours());
    d1.setMinutes(new Date().getMinutes());
    var ftimec=d1.getHours()+":"+d1.getMinutes();
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=ftimec;

    if (take_input==ftimec) {
        if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
            // If it's okay let's create a notification
            var notification = new Notification("Remainder Time Has Reached "+take_input);
        }
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() { CheckTime(take_input);}, 1000)
    }

}
</script>

<script>
function notifyMe() {
    var input = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    //below displays the entered time by user
    document.getElementById('input').innerHTML=input;

    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
    }
    else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        // If it's okay let's create a notification
        var notification = new Notification("Remainder Set at "+input);
    }
    // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
    else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
            // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
            if (permission === "granted") {
                var notification = new Notification("Denied");
            }
        });
    }
    window.setTimeout("CheckTime(input)",1000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check if you have granted the permission to the browser to show notification.

Comment: are you see any errors in console?